# Do I need to use Nutch to crawl local files if I want to index them?

Tags: solr, elasticsearch, nutch

My understanding of using Nutch is to download the web page to local filesystem so ElasticSearch / Solr can index it.

If I want to index local filesystem, since all the files are in the local filesystem already, do I still need to use Nutch for that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can get Nutch to crawl the filesystem if the files are already there. You'll need to activate the `protocol-file` plugin.

Alternatively [Behemoth](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/behemoth) is also a good option. Look at its Apache Tika module for extracting the text and metadata from the original docs, as well as the solr module.

Answer (score 1):

You can use data import handler. See 
https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#FileListEntityProcessor